# ArrayList VS Vector JVM Memory usage

Tags: java, memory, vector, arraylist

Does using an ArrayList take less memory when compared to Vector? I have read Vector doubles its internal array size when vector reaches the max size where as ArrayList does it only by half? Is this a true statement? I need the answer when I do not declare Vector with the values for  initialcapacity and capacityIncrement.

Comment: Vectors are considered obsolete so there is little reason to use them anyway. And the JDK comes with the source code, so a quick look at the `add` method should give you your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the original question:
`ArrayList` by default will grow the capacity by half of the current capacity. However, at any time, the program may call `ensureCapacity` to set the capacity to an appropriately large value.

`Vector` by default will grow the capacity by doubling. However, there is a constructor that allows setting the grow amount. Using a small grow value will have a negative impact on performance. Additionally, you could actually get less capacity since each grow requires a duplicate array to exist in memory for a short period of time.

In a comment, the OP has stated:

> The application pulls huge data set and we are currently facing out of memory due to maxing out the heap size

First, both `Vector` and `ArrayList` will throw an `OutOfMemoryError` if the program tries to grow the capacity beyond a set limit. You need to be sure that the OOME does not originate from the `hugeCapacity` method of the `Vector` class. If this is the case, then perhaps you could try a `LinkedList`.

Second, what is your current heap size? The default JVM heap size is rather small. The intent is to avoid pauses or choppy behavior from a full GC becoming apparent to the user of an applet. However, the heap size is also often far to small for a reasonably sophisticated application or a fairly dumb service. The `-Xmx` JVM arg could be used to increase the heap size.

Comment: The problem on hand is we are defining a vector in our application and do not set any capacity. So the vector grows by default. Further we are pulling a huge dataset from DB. We do not know the size of the data set before hand and it depends upon the data for particular scenarios. We are getting the OOM issue often and when analyzed the heap dump the vendor team suggested that the Vector object for that particular TXN was using 75% of the heap size when OOM happened.We are trying various approaches to reduce the size of this vector and replacing it with ArrayList was one of the suggestion.

Comment: We have more than one JVM and the OOM happens in one of the JVM only and not on all. Each JVM has a heap size of 1.2 GB

Comment: It is possible to increase the heap above 1.2 GB if a small increase would resolve the situation. Or perhaps it is possible not to pull in all of the data at once? Maybe keep a cursor open with the DB?

Comment: There are lot of options but the application is kind of old and been there for a while. so revamp of the code is not a choice but to fine tune it with what we have at this point of time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct in terms of memory allocation of internal arrays:

Internally, both the ArrayList and Vector hold onto their contents using an Array. When an element is inserted into an ArrayList or a Vector, the object will need to expand its internal array if it runs out of room. A Vector defaults to doubling the size of its array, while the ArrayList increases its array size by 50 percent.

**Correction**

It is not always that these Vector will double up the capacity. It may just increase its size upto the increment mentioned in the constructor    :

```
public Vector(int initialCapacity, int capacityIncrement)
```

The logic in grow method is to increase the capacity to double if increment not mentioned, otherwise use the capacityIncrement, here is the code of Vector grow method:

```
private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + ((capacityIncrement > 0) ?
                                     capacityIncrement : oldCapacity);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming it.

Comment: I was only referring to the default declaration of Vector and not using the constructor with capacityIncrement limit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no comparison between `Vector` and `ArrayList` as they fit different purposes. `Vector` was supposed to be a concurrency safe `List` implementation. However, the design of the class was severely flawed and did not provide concurrency guarantees for the most common use case of iteration.

`Vector` itself is easily replaced with [Collections.synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)(new ArrayList()). The result of course contains the same flaw as `Vector`. `Vector` should be considered deprecated.

The use of `Vector` is a now a mark for naivety in understanding Java and concurrent programming. Don't use it.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. This is an old application and it still uses Vectors. The application pulls huge data set and we are currently facing out of memory due to maxing out the heap size. Hence one of the suggestion is using ArrayList than Vectors.

Comment: You asked the wrong question! When you say it "maxes out the heap" I immediately have to ask "What is the heap size?" Are you really maxing out 4Gb of memory? If so, do you really need it all in memory at once? If you know the size of the data set, why not just set the initial capacity appropriately?

Comment: It's unlikely the Vector usage was/is the actual problem.

Vector was the bare minimum at least available dynamic sized list for a loong time on mobile java for example. the cldc had only that as a dynamic sized array kind of data store list object. (cldc had a list class but it's not the list you're thinking of). the cldc version of it is pretty cut down and unbloated too and inherits directly out of Object.  It was a pretty nice class and never caused me any memory problems either, also it wasn't too slow.. 

still, the full jdk Vector shouldn't be the culprit for massive memory use.